# Connections to some sites time out from OS X but not from Windows, how to diagnose?

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, network

For the past couple of weeks I have noticed some sites take longer to finish loading. GMail would be one example; after the site is loaded and fully usable, the spinning indicator in Chrome’s tabs will remain for a couple of minutes. Safari behaves the same. Right now reddit doesn’t load at all. Pinging `www.reddit.com` results in 100% packet loss. Their address resolves to an Akamai IP, so if everything delivered via Akamai is timing out, that would explain why quite a lot of sites are affected.

Loading those same sites from my boot camp partition works like a charm, same goes for my iPod, so the router as well as the ISP can be ruled out as the reason for this. What can iIdo now to diagnose the problem?

Comment: Try resetting your network settings

Comment: Try using the Traceroute feature of Network Utility to see where the packets stop.

Answer (score 1):

"Do pages often "stall" and then time out halfway through loading? (And then you hit the "stop" button, and refresh, and magically, they appear?) I just had this happen, and fixed it by manually turning "off" IPV6 (from the default setting of "Automatic") in the Advanced area of the Network settings control panel. "

I found this tip to work in conjunction with setting my DNS to google or freeDNS.

Comment: No, they never stopped loading, and canceling and retrying didn't help. DNS was also one of the things i ended up trying, and changed it from Google's (which i had before) to my ISP's. This combined with running "Diagnostics" from network preferences seems to have fixed things, at least for the sites i had problems with. Still no idea what has caused the problem or if it's gone for good, but at least it seems to work now.

Comment: Turning off IPv6 is a nice troubleshooting step, but really will start becoming a liability. Better to use it to determine how/why your router or ISP is breaking things with IPv6 enabled. Many new Lion features work much better with IPv6 enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Safari has a debug option to let you inspect the hundreds of elements that have to load for large sites.

Look at the timeline and errors parts first.

Also, you might want to check for any extensions or other toolbars or code that runs within safari to filter the data before safari renders your page.

A third tip would be to make a new user on the Mac to be sure cookies or local storage on the Mac isn't contributing to the gmail wep app problems.